# gfortran can not catch obviously uninitialized variables by using -Wmaybe-uninitialize

Tags: fortran, gfortran

It seems that gfortran's -Wmaybe-uninitialize option is not clever enough to catch obviously uninitialized variables. For example:

```
program main
implicit none
integer:: i,j
j=i
write(*,*) i
end program
```

$ gfortran -Wall   -Wmaybe-uninitialized main.f90

gives no warning. But when commenting out the write statement, gfortran gives correct warning information. This is subtle.

Comment: You might state what version of gfortran you use. Either `-Wall` or `-Wuninitialized` generate the warning with gfortran 7.2.0. `-Wall -Wmaybe-uninitialized` do warn as well but only `-Wmaybe-uninitialized` is not sufficient. The variable has an obvious uninitialized character here.

Comment: The version of gfortran I am using is little old, it is version 4.8.4 . Thanks for the information that newer version of gfortran is much clever. @PierredeBuyl

Comment: @evets  I am not blaming goftran and appreciate that we have free compilers such as gfortran. I just talk about a possible bug in an old version of gfortran that can be easily solved and was actually solved by a newer version of gfortran, as pointed out by Pierre. "maybe" seems to should include the obvious maybe-uninitialized case I am talking about.

Answer (score 3):

Either `-Wall` or `-Wuninitialized` generate the warning with gfortran 7.2.0. `-Wall -Wmaybe-uninitialized` do warn as well but only `-Wmaybe-uninitialized` is not sufficient. The variable has an obvious uninitialized character here.

Consider updating gfortran to a more recent version.